# Is the new SO toolbar/UI coming to SciFi.SE?

Tags: support

**Is there a plan to implement Stack Overflow's recent toolbar/UI update here on scifi.se?**

I know some people like it and some people hate it... I'm more just irritated that it's different from site to site :-)

I would assume it'll be rolled out to other SE sites slowly but I was curious if there was a set schedule for that somewhere.

Comment: There is not yet iirc.

Comment: @Riker - No plan at all? Or just no schedule yet?

Comment: No schedule yet.

Comment: [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/191489)

Comment: Why did you have to remind me?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, but we don't know when.

From Stack Exchange employee [Paweł](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/225016/pawe%c5%82) on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343268/is-the-new-top-bar-going-to-be-rolled-out-to-all-se-sites-in-the-future#comment444520_343268):

> yes, we're planning to update existing top bar on other sites in the network to be more in line with the new one on Stack Overflow. and it's gonna be mostly about structure and layout rather than redesigning it completely (like we did for SO). we don't have exact date for launching it network-wide but it's definitely on our roadmap.